# SWReveal - CoreAnimation warnings: stiffness/damping must be greater than 0

Tags: swift, swrevealviewcontroller

I have integrated SWReveal into my app after running tests in a seperate project.

I downloaded SWReveal (latest = v2.4) from [here](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController) and followed tutorial on [AppCoda](http://www.appcoda.com/sidebar-menu-swift/).

In the stand alone project I had no issues. However inside my app (still running as a set of standalone view controllers/table, I am getting these two warnings:

```
CoreAnimation: stiffness must be greater than 0.
CoreAnimation: damping must be greater than or equal to 0.
```

Warnings go away if I either disable all aspects of scrolling or enable all of them. This is not the same as the sample project I got from AppCoda (where I get no warnings output to the console).

Although it is not an issue, I would like to try and understand the cause of this error.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you resolve ? i have the same problem

Comment: Nope. Wrote my own side menu in swift and integrated that into my app.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not 100% sure, I can't explain why and I'm not sure if this is of any help, but changing lines:

```
if (abs(nowPoint.x - _beginPoint.x) > kDirectionPanThreshold)
    _dragging = YES;
else if (abs(nowPoint.y - _beginPoint.y) > kDirectionPanThreshold)
    self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed;
```

in `SWRevealViewController.m` -> `- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`

to:

```
if (fabs(nowPoint.x - _beginPoint.x) > kDirectionPanThreshold)
    _dragging = YES;
else if (fabs(nowPoint.y - _beginPoint.y) > kDirectionPanThreshold)
    self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed;
```

seem to have made the warnings disappear for me.